# Formal theory on floating point numbers?

Tags: reference-request, floating-point

Is there a formal theory involving the set of floating point numbers? Like topological properties, analytic properties, etc. There's no abstract theory involving floating point set? I usually find a lot of stuff in engineering strictly related to implementation, but nothing in terms of abstract theory.

Comment: The set of floating point numbers (of a fixed width) is finite, so any Hausdorff topology on it is discrete. But you could take a look at [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis), it deals amongst other things with propagation of round-off errors and stuff like that.

Comment: I know that what I'm looking for could sound weird but... concept of measure, integration, not only topological are not defined at all?  Numerical analysis studies, mostly, analytical models suitable for computer arithmetic. But I'd be interested in a more abstract point of view on the subject, is there anything like that?

Comment: I've been looking a bit, but it seems every book or article dealing with floating points has applications in mind (which is not unreasonable, given how frequently floating point numbers are used in the real world). The closed thing I could find to a coherent Theory of Floating Point numbers is [this book](https://books.google.it/books?id=baFvrIOPvncC), but it is still very practical-minded (but I've only looked for a few minutes, so let's hope someone else will find something better).

Comment: By the way, since there is a natural map from $\mathbb{R}$ to the set of floating point numbers, one could consider the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure to the set of floating points. Since the latter is finite, this means that the floating point numbers themselves have non-zero measure. It might be interesting to investigate this measure, and see if it gives rise to a reasonable notion of integrable functions etc.

Comment: Does number theory or analytic number theory treat the subject?

Comment: VERY far out suggestion. Look at the surreal numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number .

Comment: What kind of theory are you looking for? It is a finite set, so much of "analysis" and such just doesn't apply at all.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in section 4.2.2, "Accuracy of Floating Point Arithmetic", in *The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Seminumerical Algorithms, Third Edition* by Donald Knuth, especially subsection A., "An axiomatic approach".  Knuth shows how to reason logically about floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Perhaps supplement with Goldberg's ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)